# What is the right way variables initialize in stateless widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am initializes in constructor but I am not sure it is the right way?

```
class PlaceDialogWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final NearbyPlace currentPlace;
  final SizeHelper sizeHelper;

  PlaceDialogWidget(
      {Key? key, required this.currentPlace, required this.sizeHelper})
      : dialogWidth = sizeHelper.width! * 0.7,
        dialogHeight = sizeHelper.height! * 0.5,
        super(key: key);

  late final double dialogWidth;
  late final double dialogHeight;
}
```

Comment: Definitely, you go with this type initialization in stateless widget

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is one way of initializing variables in Dart.

Dart as a language has many interesting features around constructors. Please see [Using constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors) for more info

`flutter` is a framework build with `dart`, so the constructor rules of `dart` apply to `flutter` as well, so a `StatelessWidget` class is like any other `dart` class.